# Why does my "delete oldest files if more than x in directory" shell script not work?

Tags: shell

Im truly sorry for this horrible title, it's the best I could phrase it.

So I have a backup scripts that creates backup tars of some server data and stores it in /server/backups, however I only need backups of the last week, therefore I created this script to run as a weekly task and clean up my backups folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
#initializing a with the amount of backup archives and b with the target max
a=find /server/backups/ -type f | wc -l
b=14

#if there are more backup files than target max
#delete the oldest files
if [ $a > $b ]
then
    ls -1t /server/backups/ | tail -n +15 | xargs rm -f
fi
```

but it doesn't work. Im very new to linux and i dont know how to "debug" this.

Comment: also, you want `-lt` and not `>`

Comment: To check a shell script for errors you can use https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

```
a=find /server/backups/ -type f | wc -l
```

This runs the command `/server/backups/` with the environment variable `a` set to `find`. Or actually it probably just gives an error because of the trailing slash.
What you want is a [command substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).

```
if [ $a > $b ]
```

The `>` here is a *string* comparison, so e.g. `2` would be greater than `14`. And you should quote the variables, but that's probably not an issue if they just hold numbers.

```
ls -1t /server/backups/ | tail -n +15 | xargs rm -f
```

Here, there's the obvious problems with filenames containing whitespace, quotes or newlines (because of how `xargs` interprets its input by default, and because `tail` deals with lines). But if we can disregard that, if your filenames are "nice", *and* you have GNU xargs, then you could just run

```
ls -t /server/backups/ | tail -n +15 | xargs -d '\n' -r rm
```

because the output from `tail` will be empty if there are less than 15 lines.
`-d '\n'` tells xargs to read full lines, instead of the possibly-quoted, whitespace separated words it does by default, and `-r` tells it to not run the command if there aren't any arguments. Neither is a standard feature.

Comment: i did change my condition to use -gt and my filenames are all consistent without whitespaces or newlines. thank you a lot for the command substitution advice!